# CMake/CTest integration with wine/qemu

Tags: c++, cmake, qemu, wine, ctest

**What I have:**

I develop native unity plugin for different platforms including

- iOS
- Android
- Windows
- OSX

I use `cmake` as build-system and `ctest` for unit-tests

My build environment - `osx`, so it's not a problem to run unit tests on osx.

Also I know that for testing Android and Windows I can use `qemu` and `wine` accordingly.

**Questions:**

- I just wondering `cmake/ctest` provide any variables to specify some emulators like `wine` or `qemu`? Or should I write some custom scripts for this?
- How can I run native unit tests on iOS (device or emulator)? Is it possible with `qemu`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR.html). Best set it in your toolchain file.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote my own solution for `wine`

`WineCTestWrapper.cmake:`

```
macro (add_wine_test_wrapper_script TEST)
    set(TESTNAME ${TEST})
    configure_file (
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/cmake/modules/WineCTestWrapper.sh.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TESTNAME} @ONLY
    )
endmacro ()
```

`WineCTestWrapper.sh.in:`

```
#!/bin/bash
# simple wrapper for windows PE-executable format

wine @TESTNAME@.exe
```

How to use it:

```
include(WineCTestWrapper)

...

find_program(WINE_FOUND wine)
add_test(some_test some_test)
if(WINE_FOUND)
    add_wine_test_wrapper_script(some_test)
endif()
```

Pay attention that by default [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) create executable with  `.exe` postfix, and this solution use this 'feature'

**Update**

Another possible somution https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-August/023534.html